# Asp.net: alternative for gridview + horizontal accordion that display a table?

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net, gridview

I need to make a table with huge data from a database, I've done it very easy with a gridview in asp.net but there is a big problem,I need to customize that table a lot.

I want something like this, with a row with data about a person and the row after with a description of projects he's in, then another row with another person data and so on.

Table:

https://ibb.co/dJmEqw

And when i click/hover on a platform(platform i want to be a accordion propriety/it can be a button too) to display a table in the right or down side.
Table inside the platform's accordion:

Hope you get the idea guys, how can I do this with horizontal table lines, tables in accordions click/hover and databind? I need to take data from database and put it in the tables I described but I don't know if i can do that with asp.net gridviews which automatically generate the rows/columns it needs or is it another method ?

Any idea, advice, code is welcome, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `GridView` is a simple "PowerPoint" solution for simple data models.

If you want more complex things get rid of the `GridView` and use a `Repeater` to create your HTML table instead. The `Repeater` control lets you create the table row tags in the `ItemTemplate`. You can easily generate *two* rows for each item in `DataSource`.

Of course, you need to generate the table cells (columns) manually as well with the `Repeater` control. Use `Literal` or `Label` controls to view the data in the table cells. Use

```
<%#: DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "propertyname") %>
```

to assign the Text properties of the controls.

Comment: I'll look after what you said, thanks, but do you have a ideea of how to make the 2nd table with rows and columns that match with a "x" ?